setState is not a function in react and nextjs
Home Page
"use client";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Loading from "./loading";
import Link from "next/link";
import Courses from "./components/courses";

export default function HomePage() {
  const { course, setCourse } = useState([]);
  const { loading, setLoading } = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchCourses() {
      const res = await fetch("/api/courses");
      const data = await res.json();
      setCourse(data);
      setLoading(false);
    }
    fetchCourses();
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <Loading />;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to next website</h1>
      <Courses courses={course} />
    </div>
  );
}

Component
import Link from "next/link";

export default function Courses({ courses }) {
  return (
    <div className="courses">
      {courses?.map((course) => (
        <div key={course.id} className="card">
          <h2>{course.title}</h2>
          <small>Level: {course.level}</small>
          <p>{course.description}</p>
          <Link href={course.link} target="_blank" className="btn">
            Go to course
          </Link>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

Just want to fetch the data from local api using "useState and useEffect" at client side page in nextjs but getting an error (setState is not a fuctions), please let me know what i'm doing wrong here.I'm new to React and Nextjs

useState returns an array, not an object; you are using the wrong syntax.

@Armen Has it, you've a typo. Change the code from const { course, setCourse } = useState([]); to const [course, setCourse[ = useState([]);, same for the loading state as well. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".

@Armen We VTC issues caused by typos on this site since they really only help the OP and aren't considered valuable in the longterm.

You are setting the state variable and setter function of the useState hook wrongly. The state variable and the setter function are supposed to be set in a destructured array and not object as you've done above. This is how you should declare a state variable using the the useState hook:
const [ course, setCourse ] = useState([]);
const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchCourses() {
      const res = await fetch("/api/courses");
      const data = await res.json();
      setCourse(data);
      setLoading(false);
    }
    fetchCourses();
  }, []);


